# using travellers cheques as proof of funds for visa

Tags: visas, canada

I want to apply for a canada visitor visa. Can i use travellers cheques as proof of funds instead of a bank statement?

Comment: I would be very surprised if you could. Bank statements show your financial situation: your income, your expenditure, your access to money over a period of time. A pile of traveller's cheques shows that, right now, you have access to some quantity of cash. How do you prove that this cash is yours? What evidence does it give that you'll still have that cash when you travel to Canada? How are you even going to prove you have the cheques? Include the cheques themselves in the application? Photocopies just prove that you have access to photocopies of traveller's cheques...

Comment: [This answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) shows why bank statements are asked.  While this is written in a UK context, it applies as well to Canada.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

Answer (score 7):

Your bank statement is much more than the sum at the end. People applying for visas ignore this to their peril. It shows you have a steady income, that you are not spending more than your income and so on. This is why people who just get their "rich uncle" dump a large sum into their account at the time of visa application often get refused.